# Generalization of the Hamiltonian path problem on Grid Graphs

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, np-hardness

Fix a cost to each of these actions: move up, move down, move left, move right. I.e. fix some function $f: \{\text{move up, move down, move left, move right}\} \to \mathbb N$.

Define the following decision problem:
$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
\begin{align*}
&\text{Weighted path}_f \\
&\text{INPUT}: \text{A grid graph $G = (V, E)$ and a bound $K > 0$.} \\
&\text{QUESTION}: \text{Is there a path $\pi$ in $G$ that visits each vertex such that cost$(\pi) \le K$?}
\end{align*} 
}
$$

How could one show that this problem is $NP$-complete? Membership to $NP$ is clear, $NP$-hardness is not.

If $f \equiv n$ for some $n$ then the problem is clearly $NP$-hard because we may choose $K = (|V|-1) \cdot n$ and the problem can be solved iff $G$ has a Hamiltonian path. But what about a non-uniform definition of $f$?

Note: By a grid graph I mean a finite, vertex induced subgraph of the integer lattice $(\mathbb Z^2, E)$ where $(u, v) \in E \iff d_{\ell_2}(u,v) = 1$.

Comment: You might start by reviewing the proof that "Hamiltonian path in a grid graph" is NP-hard, checking what are the challenges or barriers to applying those techniques to your problem, and [edit]ing your post to summarize what you've found.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The problem can be NP-hard if $f$ is constant. Is your question whether there exist non-constant functions $f$ such that this is NP-hard? Or whether this is NP-hard for all functions $f$?

Comment: The latter. I.e. find all $f$ for which the problem is NP-hard.